# pivot_longer a grouped summary statistics data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, pivot

I have a wide, grouped data frame that has summary statistics. I would like to make it a long data frame but maintain the grouped structure. What's complicating my use of `tidy::pivot_longer` is that my variable names have many underscores `_` so this will fail:

```
summary_statistics %>%
  pivot_longer(
    cols = -major,
    names_to = c("metric", ".value"),
    names_sep = "_"
  )
```

**This is an example of what I would like my full dataset to look like:**

[image]

**This is a sample of my data; it only has two groups:**

```
structure(list(major = c("Agricultural Production Crops", "Agricultural Services"
), K_int_median = c(34.9282238037279, 77.9070702646621), K_phys_median = c(106.956, 
18.7935), Intangibles_intensity_median = c(0.32501505086627, 
0.709643043866057), g_k_it_to_K_int_median = c(0, 0.000907566377724797
), total_q_median = c(0.763614490107275, 1.01797163208658), i_phys_median = c(0.047126401975899, 
0.0276051183516769), i_int_median = c(0.0543444120160464, 0.0683764146679363
), i_tot_median = c(0.124471781089083, 0.087877194060611), c_tot_median = c(0.0907351115933735, 
0.107703017882946), operating_activities_net_cash_flow_median = c(9.345, 
4.1815), investing_activities_net_cash_flow_median = c(-9.704, 
-8.035), financing_activities_net_cash_flow_median = c(-0.187, 
-0.02), tobins_q_star_median = c(1.1101884963599, 4.65296310474643
), tobins_q_median = c(1.17536540117199, 1.28933085685286), i_phys_star_median = c(0.0772462451739071, 
0.0932664752349519), c_star_median = c(0.0800104233961813, 0.282089718861792
), K_int_mean = c(760.050870588553, 491.497287243701), K_phys_mean = c(775.888854341737, 
185.244767857143), Intangibles_intensity_mean = c(0.345883285225805, 
0.631417445616549), g_k_it_to_K_int_mean = c(0.132005563829027, 
0.142655926892322), total_q_mean = c(1.3957823653672, 1.33464901551012
), i_phys_mean = c(0.169384663751851, 0.0312492565002166), i_int_mean = c(0.0884951078166561, 
0.0844910735640263), i_tot_mean = c(0.257879771568507, 0.115740330064243
), c_tot_mean = c(0.122917654710874, 0.143812487843156), operating_activities_net_cash_flow_mean = c(144.367893557423, 
66.1194821428571), investing_activities_net_cash_flow_mean = c(-88.623106442577, 
-67.8837857142857), financing_activities_net_cash_flow_mean = c(-44.3873921568627, 
5.46823214285714), tobins_q_star_mean = c(2.56816328378432, 4.63391170250191
), tobins_q_mean = c(1.82514874677354, 1.60223509883476), i_phys_star_mean = c(0.301377701942308, 
0.102902112202636), c_star_mean = c(0.0287688891422042, 0.167090867297689
), K_int_sd = c(2680.6706553, 747.224386945346), K_phys_sd = c(1780.60956142719, 
285.714488806952), Intangibles_intensity_sd = c(0.255299960589669, 
0.198775601347881), g_k_it_to_K_int_sd = c(0.216533571569935, 
0.223658024222624), total_q_sd = c(1.83386076296874, 1.62678431347242
), i_phys_sd = c(1.62639416268422, 0.040440137294083), i_int_sd = c(0.106362336605973, 
0.0820372257699696), i_tot_sd = c(1.6311909163629, 0.0857492878030806
), c_tot_sd = c(0.506290469946353, 0.233685418707418), operating_activities_net_cash_flow_sd = c(499.93938856159, 
98.7911450165064), investing_activities_net_cash_flow_sd = c(274.673602674002, 
130.119384773958), financing_activities_net_cash_flow_sd = c(308.644312649905, 
68.6755002986684), tobins_q_star_sd = c(4.44338640808461, 3.84562465895279
), tobins_q_sd = c(1.72830283041568, 1.02883274327846), i_phys_star_sd = c(3.0436822022336, 
0.0890400152571432), c_star_sd = c(2.18047328457482, 0.572386085210407
), K_int_skewness = c(5.38907414261696, 1.56607770266072), K_phys_skewness = c(3.97687904859712, 
1.50680102243183), Intangibles_intensity_skewness = c(0.382061602552739, 
-0.571717747737949), g_k_it_to_K_int_skewness = c(1.5554881729664, 
1.10449370505179), total_q_skewness = c(2.70129968563368, 2.13168246549811
), i_phys_skewness = c(18.4521610998422, 5.48216190420597), i_int_skewness = c(2.99267652871199, 
1.98118917058246), i_tot_skewness = c(18.2941620026543, 2.20470614072453
), c_tot_skewness = c(10.7658656911522, 2.21050134140213), operating_activities_net_cash_flow_skewness = c(4.71523318498908, 
1.46427065577834), investing_activities_net_cash_flow_skewness = c(-4.7061234049821, 
-3.85176287526975), financing_activities_net_cash_flow_skewness = c(-7.13649407215263, 
4.19060210870064), tobins_q_star_skewness = c(4.76894251606614, 
0.381561849301529), tobins_q_skewness = c(3.4504869837413, 1.57475698535686
), i_phys_star_skewness = c(18.5033181650621, 1.25060482803011
), c_star_skewness = c(-1.55626192070213, -2.81032297367039)), row.names = c(NA, 
-2L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Reminder about the *minimal* part of [mcve]: do we really need all these columns in order to recreate the issue, or would, say, 1 or 2 variables (and their respective mean, median, sd) suffice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple instances of `_` in the column name so, we may use `names_pattern` to capture characters as a group i.e. the 'metric' column should get all the characters before the `_` (`.*`) and the value columns (`.value`) would be one or more characters that are not a `_` (`[^_]+`) till the end (`$`) of the string in column name

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
summary_statistics %>% 
   pivot_longer(cols = -major, names_to = c("metric", ".value"), 
         names_pattern = "(.*)_([^_]+)$")
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 32 × 6
   major                         metric                               median     mean       sd skewness
   <chr>                         <chr>                                 <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>
 1 Agricultural Production Crops K_int                               34.9    760.     2681.       5.39 
 2 Agricultural Production Crops K_phys                             107.     776.     1781.       3.98 
 3 Agricultural Production Crops Intangibles_intensity                0.325    0.346     0.255    0.382
 4 Agricultural Production Crops g_k_it_to_K_int                      0        0.132     0.217    1.56 
 5 Agricultural Production Crops total_q                              0.764    1.40      1.83     2.70 
 6 Agricultural Production Crops i_phys                               0.0471   0.169     1.63    18.5  
 7 Agricultural Production Crops i_int                                0.0543   0.0885    0.106    2.99 
 8 Agricultural Production Crops i_tot                                0.124    0.258     1.63    18.3  
 9 Agricultural Production Crops c_tot                                0.0907   0.123     0.506   10.8  
10 Agricultural Production Crops operating_activities_net_cash_flow   9.35   144.      500.       4.72 
# … with 22 more rows
```

---

With `names_sep` we can use `_` with a regex lookaround to suggest that there are no more `_` till the end (`$`) of the string that follows the `_`

```
summary_statistics %>%
  pivot_longer(
    cols = -major,
    names_to = c("metric", ".value"),
    names_sep = "_(?=[^_]+$)"
  )
# A tibble: 32 × 6
   major                         metric                               median     mean       sd skewness
   <chr>                         <chr>                                 <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>
 1 Agricultural Production Crops K_int                               34.9    760.     2681.       5.39 
 2 Agricultural Production Crops K_phys                             107.     776.     1781.       3.98 
 3 Agricultural Production Crops Intangibles_intensity                0.325    0.346     0.255    0.382
 4 Agricultural Production Crops g_k_it_to_K_int                      0        0.132     0.217    1.56 
 5 Agricultural Production Crops total_q                              0.764    1.40      1.83     2.70 
 6 Agricultural Production Crops i_phys                               0.0471   0.169     1.63    18.5  
 7 Agricultural Production Crops i_int                                0.0543   0.0885    0.106    2.99 
 8 Agricultural Production Crops i_tot                                0.124    0.258     1.63    18.3  
 9 Agricultural Production Crops c_tot                                0.0907   0.123     0.506   10.8  
10 Agricultural Production Crops operating_activities_net_cash_flow   9.35   144.      500.       4.72 
# … with 22 more rows
```

Comment: Can you please explain what the regex code is saying?